# Updating bindings defined via XAML and x:Bind (C++/CX)

Tags: data-binding, win-universal-app, c++-cx

The following code can be used to induce updating of XAML via x:Bind

```
public ref class MyEntry sealed : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public:
    virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged( Platform::String^ propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChanged( this, ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }  
    ...
    property String^ Text1
    ...
```

now, if something changes in a `MyEntry` object, e.g. a property defined as `Text1` we call `OnPropertyChanged( "Text1" )` to induce an update in the view.

**Now the concern**: The string "Text1" has to match the property definition, but there is no way to assure this at compile time. Neither do I know a way to catch this at runtime.

Comment: Having done some testing, the behaviour of `PropertyChanged` seems to work like this: 

Passing an empty string (or even `nullptr`) as the `propertyName`, will correctly update the binding, and the update will even be transported up through the view tree. But if passing a specific name, only the matching element will be updated. Nifty, but is there any documentation?

Comment: For documentation you can refer to [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx): The PropertyChanged event can indicate that all properties on the object have changed by using String.Empty for the PropertyName property of the PropertyChangedEventArgs. The PropertyChanged event can indicate that indexer properties on the object have changed by using a PropertyName value of "Item[indexer]" for specific indexers or "Item[]" for all indexers. Note that C++ does not currently support binding to indexers.